# Using iptables to show users from specified IP a website

Tags: iptables, .htaccess, spam

I'm currently using iptables to block access to known ip ranges used by spam servers (specifically Ubiquity servers). My concern is that over time I know that ip ranges can change hands and I don't want the possibility of ever blocking legitimate users.

Rather than just drop the connection via -j DROP is it possible to direct that IP range to a single webpage that would say something like "We think you're a spammer. If you're not please email us"? Can this be done via iptables? Or do I need to use htaccess for this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with iptable. For example, you can DNAT them to another public IP on a server hosting the single webpage.

Comment: could you possibly give me an example rule that would do that?

Comment: I have not anymore since I stopped using iptable but if you add -s 1.2.3.4 and --dport 80, 1.2.3.4 being the ip of the spammer, you can try using example #1 of chapter 6.2 http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html